# Solr - Merge similar terms in facet ?

Tags: solr, collation, facet

I am using the facet feature of Solr to retrieve the most frequent indexes of my documents and I was wondering whether or not it is possible to "merge" together the frequencies of similar terms (e.g. with help of the levenshtein distance).

*Consider for example:*
"Communication skills" appearing 200 times and "Communicating skills" appearing 100 times, is if possible to bring Solr to return "Communication skills : 300 times" ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Solr creates facets on what you insert. So if you insert `Communication skills` and `Communicating skills` it wouldn't understand whether to combine it or not.

However, what you can do is use the `SynonymFilterFactory` where you would have to define that `Communication skills` is a synonym of `Communicating skills` in a file and Solr will replace `Communicating skills` with `Communication skills`.

**EDIT**

You can also use the `PorterStemFilterFactory` to stem the words, however, this works on single tokens so that would mean breaking into tokens and then stemming and then some how joining them back. This also has adverse effects because of stemming.

Comment: Thank you Junaid for your answer :)
However I have no mean to know these "synonyms" beforehand. Is there a way to tell Solr to compute "synonyms" on the fly ? 
Can I bring Solr to understand that [word 1] and [word 2] are "synonyms" if their levenhstein distance is <= 2 ?